# How to change the resolution of camera while recording video in WP8

Tags: camera, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, resolution, video-recording

I am using the video recording sample provided by microsoft [here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Video-Recorder-Sample-5e800bbf/sourcecode?fileId=62827&pathId=1813816892). I want to change the resolution of the video being recorded in my app. Currently its recording in highest resolution by default. How to do so?

```
videoCaptureDevice.DesiredFormat = new VideoFormat(PixelFormatType.Unknown, 480, 640, 30);
```

The above statement is throwing Argument Exception.

Also, if possible let me know how to capture from the front camera?

How to achieve this? Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Second parameter for `AudioVideoCaptureDevice.OpenAsync` is the resolution. And you can get the resolutions using `AudioVideoCaptureDevice.GetAvailableCaptureResolutions(sensor)`.

Comment: do you know why in front camera the camera feed is 180 degree rotated?

Comment: The camera is always recording in landscape.

Comment: hey claus, i realize that AudioVideoCaptureDevice might be the best solution for recording videos in WP8, however I am unable to find any samples or help in that. I have posted a similar question for it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17898769/how-to-record-video-using-audiovideocpturedevice-in-wp8. Can you help? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this one.

```
private AudioVideoCaptureDevice VideoRecordingDevice;
private Windows.Foundation.Size resolution = new Windows.Foundation.Size(320, 240);
VideoRecordingDevice = await AudioVideoCaptureDevice.OpenAsync(CameraSensorLocation.Back, resolution);
```

NB: Remember that it may only used for wp8 or later version.

Answer (score -1):

The Solution is (With my knowledge)

```
     VideoCaptureDevice webcam = CaptureDeviceConfiguration.GetDefaultVideoCaptureDevice();

 int videoformatcount = webcam.SupportedFormats.Count(); //We will get the avilable video format

  if (videoformatcount > 0)
             {
                var Temp = webcam.SupportedFormats;

                VideoFormat objVideoFormat = Temp[videoformatcount - 1];

                webcam.DesiredFormat = new VideoFormat(PixelFormatType.Format8bppGrayscale, objVideoFormat.PixelWidth, objVideoFormat.PixelHeight, 1);
            }

captureSource.VideoCaptureDevice = webcam;
```

This will produce the lowest resolution video

Comment: do you know why in front camera the camera feed is 180 degree rotated?

Comment: Sorry!i don't know..you can go thorough these links and may be it will help you [link](http://www.mindscapehq.com/blog/index.php/2012/02/28/windows-phone-7-working-with-camera-tasks/) [link] (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh708750.aspx)

Comment: Because the camera always record in landscape. @Vicky your code is guesswork, it's not a appropriate solution at all.

Answer (score -1):

Use AudioVideoCaptureDevice to recoed video

```
StorageFolder isoStore = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFolderAsync("Shared");
            var file = await isoStore.CreateFileAsync("foos1.wmv", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
            using (var s = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
            {
                Windows.Foundation.Size resolution = new Windows.Foundation.Size(640, 480);
                avDevice = await AudioVideoCaptureDevice.OpenAsync(CameraSensorLocation.Back,
                    AudioVideoCaptureDevice.GetAvailableCaptureResolutions(CameraSensorLocation.Back).Last());

                VideoBrush videoRecorderBrush = new VideoBrush();
                videoRecorderBrush.SetSource(avDevice);

                viewfinderRectangle.Fill = videoRecorderBrush;

                await avDevice.StartRecordingToStreamAsync(s);

                Thread.Sleep(30000);


                await avDevice.StopRecordingAsync();



            }


            new MediaPlayerLauncher()
            {
                Media = new Uri(file.Path, UriKind.Relative),
            }.Show();
```